# Select sum from latest values in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

```
SELECT SUM(CD.[Value]) AS [Value]
    FROM [{schema}].[CompanyData] CD
        INNER JOIN #Locations T
            ON T.LocationId = CD.CompanyId
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT CDM.CompanyId, MAX(CDM.[Date]) as MaxDate
            FROM [{schema}].[CompanyData] CDM
                INNER JOIN #Locations T
                    ON T.LocationId = CDM.CompanyId
            GROUP BY CDM.CompanyId
        ) TM 
            ON CD.CompanyId = TM.CompanyId AND CD.[Date] = TM.MaxDate
```

I have query to select `SUM` from latest values for each row with different `CompanyId`.

Is this double join of same tables (Query and subQuery) fine or I can improve somehow it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The query you showed is not running as-is, where's this CFID alias coming from?

As SQL Server supports Standard SQL's Analytical Functions you might rewrite MAX/Subquery using RANK (or ROW_NUMBER):

```
SELECT ...
FROM
  ( SELECT CDM.CompanyId, 
           any additonal columns you need,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CDM.CompanyId
                        ORDER BY CDM.[Date] DESC) AS rnk
        FROM [{schema}].[CompanyData] CDM
            INNER JOIN #Locations T
                ON T.LocationId = CDM.CompanyId
  ) TM
WHERE rnk = 1
```